# Replacing values in formated file with python

Tags: python, file

I have a string see attached file like that and i would like to modify it using a function

Giving section name  parameter name and value to set

Also in case i want to modify several parameters for a same section how can i have position 
in file to avoid scanning x time for a same section :

```
&NAM_WRITE_COVER_TEX CLANG='FR'
/
&NAM_FRAC LECOCLIMAP = T
/
&NAM_PGD_GRID PGRID = 'CONF PROJ '
/
&NAM_CONF_PROJ_GRID 
XLATCEN=43.,
XLONCEN=0.
NIMAX=12, 
NJMAX=8, 
XDX=60000., 
XDY=60000. /
&NAM_CONF_PROJ 
XLAT0=43., XLON0=0., XRPK=1.0, XBETA=0. /
/
&NAM_PGD_SCHEMES CNATURE = 'ISBA' , 
CSEA = 'SEAFLX' , 
CTOWN = 'TEB' , 
CWATER = 'WATFLX' ,
LGARDEN = F
/
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use XML or a formatted Excel file? Python has plenty of libraries to edit these types of files directly

Comment: Is this a documented format, if so there may already be a module to do what you want. Otherwise I would say that this format looks a lot like the `ini` file format for which [there is already a module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).

Comment: yes this is namelist file ( kind of ini file) used by a fortran program. i haven't choice to use other format.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest using python regular expressions. http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. The regular expression will only use one pass.

```
def replace_value(matchobj):
    new_repl_dict = {'XLATCEN': 54, 'XDX': 7000, 'CTOWN': "'NEW_VAL'"}
    if matchobj.group(1) in new_repl_dict: 
        return matchobj.group(1) + matchobj.group(2) + new_repl_dict[matchobj.group(1)]

file = "&NAM_WRITE_COVER_TEX CLANG='FR'\n..."
re.sub('(XLATCEN|XDX|CTOWN)(\s*=\s*)([^\n]*)', replace_value, file)
```

Comment: @ johnthexii,Python ConfigParser looks interesting do you think i can add specific structure like '&' as begin section tag '/' as end of section

Comment: @ Victor, do you think it is possible to filter replace to specify which section is concerned by change because a same parameter name could exist in differents sections

Comment: thanks to one who give (-1) my question is not a simple search and replace this no needs a post, what i want to do is a little bit more complicated , but this needs to really understand the problem !!!